# Remove shower cartridge clip

Tags: plumbing

Am trying to replace a worn shower cartridge which is held in place by cartridge retaining clip. But I could not pull the retaining clip with long nose pliers. Any helpful tips appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not sure but it looks like something needs to turn to release.  Nice big slots at top and bottom at might catch something to turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small hole under the top of the clip. Get a small flat screwdriver or an awl in that hole and pry down.  If still too hard to remove use the flat blade screwdriver on the sides of the clip and tap with a hammer to get some shock in them to loosen them, then pry the top up.

Comment: Thank you! So I went to get my old sock soak it in very hot water and left it on top of that clip for five minutes. Then I removed the sock and went straight away to tap the top of the clip with the small screwdriver with a hammer. And yes, it loosened.  My follow-up question,  if I may, is, how do I clean the inside after removing the shower cartridge? On my way to home center to buy a new retaining clip and maybe pick something up to clean the inside of that thing

Comment: There are tools made to clean the bore for the cartridge, however some waterproof 320 grit sandpaper or emery cloth rolled into a cylinder and gently run into the bore will do the trick.  Most of the debris in there are minerals from the water.

Answer (score 0):

Your cartridge is rotated clockwise a few degrees, thus putting pressure on the clip, jamming it against the housing. Try rotating the cartridge counter-clockwise so the raised lips line up with the slots on the top and bottom of the housing. Then the clip should be easier to pull out.